# MySQL: select 5 rows before and after specific row

Tags: mysql

I have table called "users" and need to select 2 rows before and after specific row, sorted by users.score ASC

users table (structure):

```
id     name     score
1      John       2
2      Sara       1
3      san        3
4      test       2
5      jery       5
6      simon      6
7      bob2       7
8      jack       4
9      man        2
```

for example: need to select 2 rows before and after users.id = 5 order by users.score

result should be like:

```
id     name     score
3      san        3
8      jack       4
5      jery       5
6      simon      6
7      bob2       7
```

thanks,

Comment: Expected result does not match with your requirement `need to select 2 rows before and after users.id = 5 order by users.score`

Comment: will simplify numbers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `union all` and subqueries to limit the records should do it:

```
select * from  users where id = 5
union all (
  select * from users 
  where score <  (select score from users where id = 5) 
  order by score desc limit 2
) 
union all (
  select * from users 
  where score > (select score from users where id = 5) 
  order by score asc limit 2
) 
order by score
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db86a/1)

Edit: I think a better method is to number the rows according to score and then select the rows with number -2 and +2 from the rows of id 5:

```
select id, name, score 
from (select 
      t.*, @rownum1 := @rownum1 + 1 as rank
      from users t, (select @rownum1 := 0) r
      order by score
     ) a,
     (select rank from (
        select t.*, 
        @rownum := @rownum + 1 as rank
        from users t, (select @rownum := 0) r
        order by score
     ) t
      where id = 5
   ) b
where b.rank between a.rank -2 and a.rank+2
order by score;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45c22/31)

Comment: it's working fine but return results (faraway) not directly close to specific user's score

Comment: @mwafi Hmm. I think normally order by can't be used inside unions but it seems MySQL might allow it, but that could explain if you get strange results. Let me think some more about an alternative.

Comment: @mwafi I've changed the answer; it should work correctly now, although the solution might not be super efficient.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated. What's wrong with a simple union?

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not sure that the order by is allowed inside the union; It's not in MSSQL that I'm more familiar with but maybe MySQL allows it; anyway the OP indicated that the results might be off so I changed it to something I know works.

Comment: @Strawberry That seems a lot better.

Comment: The only problem with the first solution seems to be a mistake in ordering, the last select should have used "ASC". It was not visible in the example since there was only two high rows.

Comment: @SamuelÅslund Ah, indeed. Good catch. I've changed my answer and reverted to the first solution, although I think the answer by Strawberry is better.

Comment: Is there any performance or other issues? Personally I thought using sub-selects was easier to read. I would have expected that a subselect would be more efficient than two joins, but I do not know enough to say either way.

Comment: this is not 100%: if another user has the same score as center user then it will be skipped

Comment: @Waqleh This is true, but maybe they should be skipped? Using row numbers would fix that, but the question doesn't specify what should happen if there are scores tied with the middle - should the row(s) with equal score count as lower or higher, or perhaps not at all, as in my proposed solution. It's impossible to say. So given the lack of information in the question it's simply not possible to claim that this solution is not 100% correct. It might be incorrect, or it might be what the OP wanted (and I guess it was as the answer was accepted).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps using `union all`

```
(
 select * from users where id < 5 order by score limit 2
)
union all
(
  select * from users where id > 5 order by score limit 2
)
```

Comment: users.id not matter, I only care about "users with scores" less than user.id = 5  "score" and "users with scores" higher than user.id = 5

Comment: Still this is a good idea, need to pay attention to the ordering (one of them should be "desc",  the other "asc" ) and add a subselect for the score from id 5 and then it should be done.

Comment: @SamuelÅslund I don't need to relay on "users.id" at all

Comment: @mwafi Have a look at jpw's first sugestion. It uses the same basic structure as this one but adds a subselect for the score of the user with id 5. And as you noted there was a problem with the ordering, since both selects used "DESC".

Answer (score 1):

```
(SELECT x.* FROM users x JOIN users y ON y.score <= x. score WHERE y.id = 5 ORDER BY score LIMIT 3)
UNION
(SELECT x.* FROM users x JOIN users y ON y.score >= x. score WHERE y.id = 5 ORDER BY score DESc LIMIT 3)
[ORDER BY score]    ;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45c22/42

Answer (score 0):

I just write the query, based on "jpw" solution (many thanks to him)

```
select * from  users where id = 5
union all (
  select * from users 
  where id in (select id from users where score < (select score from users u where u.id = 5) order by score ASC)
  order by score desc limit 2
) 
union all (
  select * from users 
  where id in (select id from users where score > (select score from users u where u.id = 5) order by score ASC)
  order by score ASC limit 2
) 
order by score
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting arbitrarily ordered rows before and after a specific id

```
SET @j = 0;
SET @i = 0;
SELECT *
FROM ( 
    SELECT id, col1, col2, ..., @j:=@j+1 AS pos
    FROM `table`
    WHERE  col1=... ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2 ASC
) AS zz
WHERE (    
    SELECT position
    FROM ( 
        SELECT id AS id2, @i:=@i+1 AS position
        FROM `table`
        WHERE  col1=... ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2 ASC
    ) AS zz
    WHERE id2=$currId
)
IN (pos-5,pos-4,pos-3,pos-2,pos-1,pos,pos+1,pos+2,pos+3,pos+4,pos+5)
```