# How to get previous record if there are same values on mysql

Tags: mysql

```
id | count
1 | 1
3 | 1
5 | 1
2 | 2
4 | 3
```

I’d like to know previous and next record.
The record after id ‘5’  is id ‘2’.
So I make this query.

```
select id from test
where id != 5 and count > 1
LIMIT 1
```

The result is ok but if I want to know the record after id ‘3’, it returns id ‘2’. I expected id ’5’.

So I changed that query.

```
select id from test
where id != 5 && count >= 1
LIMIT 1
```

But it returns the wrong result again.
It returns id ‘1’

How can I get the previous or next record if there are same values?
Please let me know.

Comment: how could it be 5 when the filter is `id !=5`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: select 5 rows before and after specific row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228273/mysql-select-5-rows-before-and-after-specific-row)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're ordering by count?
If you want to select the next value of 5, It should be like this:
 1. First, you need to add an order number to your result.
 2. Then get the result you want by filtering the row_number.

```
SELECT row_number 
FROM  
        (SELECT id, @rownum := @rownum + 1 as row_number
         FROM test
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r ORDER by count) T1
WHERE id = 5
INTO @concreate_order_number;

SELECT id
    FROM
        (SELECT id, @rownum := @rownum + 1 as row_number
         FROM test
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r ORDER by count) T2
    WHERE row_number > @concreate_order_number
    LIMIT 1;
```